# regex find string between 2 characters, seperated by comma

Tags: java, regex

I am new to regular expression and i want to find a string between two characters,

I tried below but it always returns false. May i know whats wrong with this ?

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input = "myFunction(hello ,world, test)";
    String patternString = "\\(([^]]+)\\)";

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(patternString);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println(matcher.group());
    }
 }
```

**Input:**

`myFunction(hello,world,test)`  where myFunction can be any characters. before starting ( there can be any characters.

**Output:**

```
hello
world
test
```

Comment: please update with your required output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest you to achieve this in a two-step process:

**Step 1:** Capture all the content between `(` and `)`

Use the regex: `^\S+\((.*)\)$`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yQaOay/1)

The first and the only capturing group will contain the required text.

**Step 2:** Split the captured string above on `,`, thus yielding all the comma-separated parameters independently.

Answer (score 2):

You could match make use of the `\G` anchor which asserts the position at the end of the previous match and and capture your values in a group:

```
(?:\bmyFunction\(|\G(?!^))([^,]+)(?:\h*,\h*)?(?=[^)]*\))
```

In Java:

```
String regex = "(?:\\bmyFunction\\(|\\G(?!^))([^,]+)(?:\\h*,\\h*)?(?=[^)]*\\))";
```

**Explanation**

- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `\bmyFunction\(` Word boundary to prevent the match being part of a larger word, match myFunction and an opening parentheses `(`
  - `|` Or
  - `\G(?!^)` Assert position at the end of previous match, not at the start of the string
- `)` Close non capturing group
- `([^,]+)` Capture in a group matching 1+ times not a comma
- `(?:\h*,\h*)?` Optionally match a comma surrounded by 0+ horizontal whitespace chars
- `(?=[^)]*\))` Positive lookahead, assert what is on the right is a closing parenthesis `)`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/53qrM0/1) | [Java demo](https://ideone.com/sVPop1)

For example:

```
String patternString = "(?:\\bmyFunction\\(|\\G(?!^))([^,]+)(?:\\h*,\\h*)?(?=[^)]*\\))";
String input = "myFunction(hello ,world, test)";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(patternString);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);

while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
```

Result

```
hello 
world
test
```

Answer (score 0):

See this you may get idea

> `([\w]+),([\w]+),([\w]+)`

**DEMO**: https://rubular.com/r/9HDIwBTacxTy2O